# What is mirror-like block on CPU?

Tags: cpu

Title speaks for itself - is that silver rectangle in the center a heat sink or circuitry?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the case used to house the internal circuitry from being damaged.  It is not a heat-sink, as it is unable to dissipate all of the heat generated by the CPU.  It does allow smooth contact for a real heat-sink to absorb and dissipate the heat.

Comment: If I have damaged the corners a little bit, it shouldn't have damaged the core, right?

Comment: No way to say for certain, you will just have to test it.

Comment: @Arturs - If the block is damaged then there is no guarantee the internal circuitry isn't damaged as well.